# How do I build a synchronous redstone binary counter in Bedrock Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

So far I have 4 T flip-flops set up to switch after a button is pressed, all I need now is a method to stop the wrong T flip-flops from activating.

The T flip-flop I'm using is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6D9_hXL0VU&t=275s)

I have 4 of these set up 3 blocks apart, and the input is a redstone line with target blocks for the bottom torch block, I have a redstone torch on the output block and I need a way to power a line that's one-directional and will power the redstone dust on the hoppers.

A few things that I'd like to add, I'm not going to add more space between them as I'm trying to make this a 4-bit counter with no unnecessary delay in either the activation or the redstone line that I need help with.